# From an architectural perspective, is it good to have all implementations of a specification in one microservice?

Tags: architecture, microservices

We have a generic solution for a business requirement for our customers. Somehow we ended up putting 4 different customer implementations (differs only by %20) into one microservice to reduce the code duplication. I can say we now have a base specification on top of each implementation. A rest parameter will decide which implementation to go with (strategy pattern).

While this sounds better than the first approach, this now brings another question to me: How good is to have another implementation on the JAR file which will never be required for that customer? The required implementation will never change for a customer. Which way to go is always the same, as the client to that microservice is still another microservice of this customer, and the call will always choose the implementation built for theirselves.

Now I wonder, since deploying unnecessary implementations on a customer environment sounds odd, what would be the best approach here?

Comment: Is that really a microservice-specific issue? I mean, wouldn't it be exactly the same if you deployed any other type of solution? You might want to look at more general strategies for multi-customer codebases instead.

Comment: @guillaume31 actually no, not really. It's just the way we are going to. You can of course think the same for a complete monolithic application still with the same concerns. It's just like, we want to avoid customer specific applications and build a "ready-to-use-out-of-the-box" application.